# How to shut down a minecraft server with python?

Tags: python, cmd, shutdown, minecraft

I have multiple minecraft servers running on the machine. servers are started with bat files that have according titles. My question is that, how can i shut down a certain minecraft server with python? Or how to kill a titled cmd.exe process with python?

Comment: how do you shutdown your servers without python?  killing the process is not a good idea, you would loose the server state.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the tools in the `os` module, it would also help if i had more information about what operating system you are using.

Comment: Using windows server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

[`os.kill`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill) to kill by PID

---

To kill by name, try [`psutil`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/). You could kill *all* you "minecrafts" that way:

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name == "minecraft.exe":
        proc.kill()
```

By exploring *psutil* you might be able to find a solution to kill *some* of them. My best bet would be by using the `cmdline` attribute of the [`Process`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Classes) class.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using autohotkey. launched autohotkey with python and made separate  .ahk files for every server.